# Вывести из двух списков два случайных значения python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, случайные-числа, print

```
import random
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [6,4,5]
print((random.choice(list1)) + (random.choice(list2)))
```

Мне нужно вывести значения списка, не добавляя их, без запятой. Например: 1 4

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вывод через запятую
Не забывайте, что массив у вас из чисел и числа с использованием знака плюс не конкатенируются, а складываются.

```
import random
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [6,4,5]
print(random.choice(list1), random.choice(list2))
```